# Change sitecore admin url /sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Is it possible to change the admin url from /sitecore to anything else so that not anyone know the admin access url of site. If yes then how it can be done.

Answer (score 5):

I don't recommend you to change admin url. 
You can restrict access to Sitecore Client in different ways.

Please check official Sitecore document about restricting access to the Sitecore client interface.
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/security_and_administration/access_rights/restrict_access_to_the_client

Answer (score 2):

You should not change that URL. It will be better if you will split your environments into Content Delivery and Content Management.

Content Management should not be accessible for someone outside your company. 
Content Delivery does not have /sitecore login page.

It means that if you will use correct architecture for your environment You will no have to change the url of login page.

Answer (score 0):

Restricting access via IIS config is the way to go here, renaming the folder is not advised.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for: 
https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/2965

Add to your redirect in the .config file as mentioned in the link. And remove the old one.